# calling protocol method that is implemented by subclass from the superclass

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, protocols

I have multiple `TableViewController` classes that inherit from a basic `TableViewController` class like this:

```
class BasicTableViewController: UITableViewController {
}

class SpecificTableViewController: BasicTableViewController {
}

class AnotherSpecificTableViewController: BasicTableViewController {
}
```

then i created a very simple protocol to add refreshing capabilities to the specific viewcontroller classes like this:

```
@objc
protocol Refreshable {
    func refresh()
}
```

my specific viewcontroller classes can implement the protocol like this:

```
class SpecificTableViewController: BasicTableViewController, Refreshable {
    func refresh() {
        getSomeDataFromServer()
    }
}
```

the question now is: what is the correct way to call the refresh method from the `BasicTableViewController` which itself does not conform to the `Refreshable` protocol? right now i am doing something like this (without being sure if it's the way to go):

```
class BasicTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let _ = self as? Refreshable {
            let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
            refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Refreshable.refresh), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
            self.refreshControl = refreshControl
        }
    }
}
```

at the very beginning i did not mark the protocol with `@objc` and tried to build the selector like this: `#selector(refresh)`. that did not work though. hope to get some clarification. :)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you want to let `BasicTableViewController` conform to `Refreshable` Protocol?

Comment: take a look at my comment to **riik**s solution. i only want to implement a refreshcontrol if a viewcontroller adopts the `Refreshable` protocol. if you have a better way to make that check you're welcome to present it. :) that is what i was asking for...

Answer (score 1):

I would let the `Superclass` implement the `Refreshable` protocol

```
protocol Refreshable {
    func refresh()
    func shouldBeRefreshable() -> Bool
}

//Making the protocol methods optional
extension Refreshable {
    func refresh() {}
    func shouldBeRefreshable() -> Bool { return false}
}

class SuperView: Refreshable {
    func addRefreshControl() {
        if shouldBeRefreshable() {
            //Add Refresh Control
        }else {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }

    func shouldBeRefreshable() -> Bool {
        //default
        return false
    }
}

//Refreshable Class
class ChildA: SuperView {
   func refresh() {
        print("Refresh in Child A")
    }
    override func shouldBeRefreshable() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

//Not Refreshable Class
class ChildB: SuperView {
}
```

Comment: the problem in this case is that my check in `viewDidLoad` will not work which i need to only add a `refreshControl` if the viewcontroller implements the `Refreshable` protocol...

Comment: this could work although i would mark the `shouldBeRefreshable` method as optional since i do not want to implement it in all subviewcontrollers that do not have refreshing capabilities...

Comment: just updated the answer ;) to make methods optional you could use a protocol extension